# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u201c' when converting series object to unicode in pandas with utf-16

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, pandas

I have a utf-16 csv file that I'm trying to load into Pandas.  By default the data comes in as an object datatype.  I plan to do some modeling with the caption column so I'd like to convert the column df['caption'] from an object to a unicode string.  Currently I'm running into the following error 'UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u201c' in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)' when doing 
df['caption']=df['caption'].astype(unicode).

I tried to solve this by using the encode and decode functions on the individual values in the df['caption'] column but I couldn't get it to work.

I'm very new to pandas and unicode so I was wondering if there's some insight as to what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Teresa

Additional information is below:

The traceback is as follows:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-aad36f4acf38> in <module>()
    10 print df['caption'].head(10)
    11 
---> 12 df['caption']=df['caption'].astype(unicode)

/opt/anaconda/envs/np18py27-1.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.pyc in astype(self, dtype, copy, raise_on_error)
   2016 
   2017         mgr = self._data.astype(
-> 2018             dtype, copy=copy, raise_on_error=raise_on_error)
   2019         return self._constructor(mgr).__finalize__(self)
   2020 

/opt/anaconda/envs/np18py27-1.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.pyc in astype(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2414 
   2415     def astype(self, *args, **kwargs):
-> 2416         return self.apply('astype', *args, **kwargs)
   2417 
   2418     def convert(self, *args, **kwargs):

/opt/anaconda/envs/np18py27-1.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.pyc in apply(self, f, *args, **kwargs)
   2373 
   2374             else:
-> 2375                 applied = getattr(blk, f)(*args, **kwargs)
   2376 
   2377             if isinstance(applied, list):

/opt/anaconda/envs/np18py27-1.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.pyc in astype(self, dtype, copy, raise_on_error, values)
    425     def astype(self, dtype, copy=False, raise_on_error=True, values=None):
    426         return self._astype(dtype, copy=copy, raise_on_error=raise_on_error,
--> 427                             values=values)
    428 
    429     def _astype(self, dtype, copy=False, raise_on_error=True, values=None,

/opt/anaconda/envs/np18py27-1.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.pyc in _astype(self, dtype, copy, raise_on_error, values, klass)
    442             # force the copy here
    443             if values is None:
--> 444                 values = com._astype_nansafe(self.values, dtype, copy=True)
    445             newb = make_block(values, self.items, self.ref_items,
    446                               ndim=self.ndim, placement=self._ref_locs,

/opt/anaconda/envs/np18py27-1.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/common.pyc in _astype_nansafe(arr, dtype, copy)
  2222         return lib.astype_intsafe(arr.ravel(), dtype).reshape(arr.shape)
  2223     elif issubclass(dtype.type, compat.string_types):
   -> 2224         return lib.astype_str(arr.ravel()).reshape(arr.shape)
  2225 
  2226     if copy:

   /opt/anaconda/envs/np18py27-1.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/lib.so in pandas.lib.astype_str (pandas/lib.c:12944)()

   /opt/anaconda/envs/np18py27-1.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/lib.so in pandas.lib.astype_str (pandas/lib.c:12862)()

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u201c' in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('Chevrolet_4-7-2014_cvid_data.csv',encoding='utf-16',header=0,na_values=['N/A',''],names=['channel','link','title','posted','views','likes','dislikes','description','category','statdate','statviews','timewatched','averagetw','subsdriven','shares','caption'])
print df.head(5)
print df.dtypes


print df['caption'].head(10)

df['caption']=df['caption'].astype(unicode)
```

The data looks like the following:

```
channel                                        link  \
0  Chevrolet  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dCayKZe6WvI   
1  Chevrolet  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IRXK35dPXbE   
2  Chevrolet  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXdj4QMw748   
3  Chevrolet  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ger32ROs94   
4  Chevrolet  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Chfm7Pou49k   
5  Chevrolet  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ySmEJyQ94BI   

                                           title       posted   views  \
0  Chevy Open House Event: From Our House to Your...  Apr  1 2014   73111   
1  Truck Towing Capabilities: 2014 Silverado -- #...  Mar 26 2014   11934   
2  Potholes at the Milford Proving Grounds: Tips ...  Mar 20 2014    8037   
3  Diesel Trucks: Heavy Duty Strengths -- 2015 Si...  Mar 20 2014   12096   
4  Captain America: All in a Day's Work -- 2014 T...  Mar 14 2014   93377   
5  Media Blasting: Camaro Engineering -- 2014 Cam...  Mar 13 2014  109931   

   likes  dislikes                                        description  \
0     43        13  In March over 100000 people visited our Chevy ...   
1    183        56  Farmer Dewayne Kleman and General Motors engin...   
2     58        10  Chevrolet vehicles are carefully designed to w...   
3    210         6  Introducing the all-new 2015 Silverado HD. The...   
4   1095        35  From saving the world to working on math homew...   

       category statdate  statviews timewatched averagetw  subsdriven  \
0  Autos & Vehicles      NaN        NaN         NaN       NaN         NaN   
1  Autos & Vehicles      NaN        NaN         NaN       NaN         NaN   
2  Autos & Vehicles      NaN        NaN         NaN       NaN         NaN   
3  Autos & Vehicles      NaN        NaN         NaN       NaN         NaN   
4  Autos & Vehicles      NaN        NaN         NaN       NaN         NaN   

   shares                                            caption  
0     NaN   The Chevy Spring Open House Sale the perfect ...  
1     NaN   0:03 A Man And His Truck And An Engineer / To...  
2     NaN   0:02 Severe Bump road sign 0:07 Pothole Facil...  
3     NaN   0:03 And there's no stronger Silverado than t...  
4     NaN   0:03 Are you doing anything fun Saturday nigh...  
5     NaN   0:05 Camaro Z/28 logo 0:07 Z/28 Bead Lock 0:0...  

[5 rows x 16 columns]
channel         object
link            object
title           object
posted          object
views           object
likes            int64
dislikes         int64
description     object
category        object
statdate        object
statviews      float64
timewatched     object
averagetw       object
subsdriven     float64
shares         float64
caption         object

dtype: object
0     The Chevy Spring Open House Sale the perfect ...
1     0:03 A Man And His Truck And An Engineer / To...
2     0:02 Severe Bump road sign 0:07 Pothole Facil...
3     0:03 And there's no stronger Silverado than t...
4     0:03 Are you doing anything fun Saturday nigh...
5     0:05 Camaro Z/28 logo 0:07 Z/28 Bead Lock 0:0...

Name: caption, dtype: object
```

Comment: Are you sure it is not already utf-16? You specified it when you read the csv

Comment: Well the thing is that doing `df['caption'].dtype` returned object as the data type...so I'm not sure.  Eventually, I want to run the dataframe in nltk and sci-kit learn for some predictive modeling so I wanted to make sure I have the right data type

Comment: `object` is the generic `dtype` for numpy for none integral types so it could well be and probably is still a utf-16 string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try adding `dtype={'caption' : str}` to your `read_csv()` call?  Like:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Chevrolet_4-7-2014_cvid_data.csv',
     encoding='utf-16',
     header=0,
     na_values=['N/A',''],
     names=[...],
     dtype={'caption' : str})
```

BTW, pandas uses `header=0` here by default.  Not that I can see your CSV but that may be redundant with your use of the `names` keyword argument, since pandas will use those column names automatically if they're in row 0 of your CSV.  But anyway, let me know if the other thing works for you. :)